# Why my file is encoding utf-8 and not ISO-8859-1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iso-8859-1

I have a JSON data and i would like download it on json file with an ISO-8859-1 encoding. This is my actual code :

```
var dataExport = "text/json;ISO-8859-1,"+ encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(formToJson(), null, 4));
    $( "<a></a>", {
      "href": "data:" + dataExport,
      "download": "config.json",
      "charset":"ISO-8859-1" 
    })
    .get(0).click()
```

This code works for download the file, but when i open it on my editor, it tell me "encoding: utf-8". How can i fix it for encoding the entire file in ISO-8859-1 ?

Thanks, and sorry for my english.

Comment: Apart from actually converting the data to ISO-8859-1 explicitly, I doubt there is an easy way.

Comment: Because when i'm reading the file with and hexadecimal editor, we can see the "é" are encoded on 16 bits, i would like 8 bits... Do you see a way ?

Comment: Like I said: without explicit conversion to ISO-8859-1 (using a lib of some sorts), I don't see an easy way. Also, how do you want to deal with characters that can't be represented in ISO-8859-1?

Comment: I won't display it for a user, i just want my application use the data in the exported file,  and my application can only deal with 8 byte charactere... So i want encode "é" with "E9" and not with "C3 A9"